# How to recognize class method passing as argument in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

With the following code, vscode doesn't seems to recognize the last method, `bot.server.test_method()` although implemented in the server class.
running result works find, but only vscode not highlight the `bot.server.test_method()` as existing method.

Anyone knows, how to make vscode recognize the `bot.server.test_method()`?

```
class mybot():
    def __init__(self, server=None):
        self.server = server

    def test_method(self):
        print('hello bot a')

class myserver():    
    def test_method(self):
        print('hello server a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = mybot(myserver())
    bot.test_method()
    bot.server.test_method()

--result--
class_test.py
hello bot a
hello server a
```

Comment: `server` does not have a Type in the `__init__` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core of the issue is that the `mybot.server` variable has no type hint associated with it in the class, so your editor does not 'know' what the type of `server` should be once it is 'inside' your bot class.

The easiest way to fix this is to just add [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), yielding:

```
class myserver():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test_method(self):
        print('hello server a')

class mybot():
    def __init__(self, server : myserver=None):
        self.server = server

    def test_method(self):
        print('hello bot a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = mybot(myserver())
    bot.test_method()
    bot.server.test_method()
```

Where the key line is `def __init__(self, server : myserver=None):`
The type hint `: myserver` for the `server` parameter tells your editor that the parameter will be of your server type.

Comment: Thank you very much, it perfectly works, but with 'myserver'=None

Answer (score 0):

The problem of not recognizing `bot.server.test_method()` is related to the way the bot variable was named. You have defined a class called `bot` and also created an instance with the same name `bot`. This can be confusing because the `bot` variable is shadowing the `bot` class.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, bot class name changed to mybot, but still vscode does not recognize as existing method in server.